# Regular Expression to match Turkey Phone number

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Regular Expression to validate the turkey phone number either in php or js

Example :  +90 (212) 123 12 12

Comment: ok now? should i work for you?

Comment: for those who might encounter, here is a regexp to solve = `/^[+]*[0-9]*[ ]{0,1}[(]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[ ]{0,1}[)]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ ]{0,1}[-\.\/]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5}$/g`

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://www.txt2re.com/index-javascript.php3?s=%2b90%20(212)%20123%2012%2012&28&17&22&18&23&19&24&27&20&25&21&26

I often use this site to do my regex. It generates code in the language you want.

Just edit what's inside the "if" once you copied the code. Magic.

Comment: link is broken!

Comment: Sorry, seems we're not in 2013 anymore :/ This txt2re.com website was so useful ! Sad to see it's currently down.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it should work in php environment

```
^\+(\d{2})\s\((\d{3})\)\s(\d{3})\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zT0lC7)

Answer (score 0):

javascript...

```
var testNumber = "+90 (212) 123 12 12";
testNumber.replace(/\D+/g,"").matches(/90\d{10}/);
```

that eliminates all non digit chars and then makes sure that you have 90 followed by 10 digits